# On shared hosting subdomain not point to my website's folder on server

Tags: apache, dns, subdomain

I have my website host on shared hosting server where other websites are also hosted.
Now I want to subdomain to point my website's folder on server.
Means if we go to the URL coolname.domain.com then it should be redirect to www.domain.com.
But It's redirected to Cpanel error page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to set an entry in your DNS zone for your subdomain.

You can also use URL Rewriting in a `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain2.com/$1
```